# after using 'for' loop, nested if does not working. why is this hapenning?

Tags: c, string, loops, nested, palindrome

If a word is not a palindrome, then just print “Not Palindrome” without quotations. If the word is a palindrome and the word is too long if its length is strictly more than 7 characters. All too long words should be replaced with a special abbreviation.like,"mmmmmabbammmmm" will be spelled as "m12m". If the word is palindrome and its length is less than or equal 7 characters.Then, just print the word.
Input Format:

The first line contains an integer T (1 ≤ T ≤ 20).
Each of the following T lines contains one word S. Where, all the letters are lowercase and possess the lengths of from 1 to 20 characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main()
{
    char s[21];
    int i, n, c = 0, t, j;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        scanf("%s", s);;
        n = strlen(s) - 1;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (s[i] == s[n - i])
                c++;
        }

        if (c == i && n > 7) {
            printf("%c%d%c\n", s[0], n - 1, s[n]);
        }
        else if (c == i && n <= 7) {
            printf("%s\n", s);
        }
        else {
            printf("Not Palindrome\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. `i` is used *twice*. The outer loop for current word [index]. And, The inner loop for leftmost char index. They conflict.
2. You are *not* resetting `c` at the start of each loop.
3. You are doing `n = strlen(s) - 1;` This is okay for the inner loop but [I think] the length calculation (e.g. `n >= 7`) is off by one?
4. No need to continue the inner loop *if* one letter compare shows that the word is *not* a palidrome (i.e. `c` should be a boolean flag).
5. Your loop does twice the work it needs to. It should stop if the left and right indexes match.
6. `scanf` by itself doesn't work too well if we have very long lines. Better to use `fgets` and `sscanf`.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated.
Note that due to the length adjustment mentioned above, the `n > 7` test *may* need to be adjusted

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char s[1000];
    int i, n, c = 0, t, j;

    // get number of words to test
    fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin);
    sscanf(s,"%d", &t);

    // test all words
    for (;  t > 0;  --t) {
        // get the word
        if (fgets(s,sizeof(s),stdin) == NULL)
            break;

        // get its length
        n = strlen(s);

        // strip newline
        if ((n > 0) && (s[n - 1] == '\n'))
            s[--n] = 0;

        // handle case of empty string or string with one letter
        c = (n > 0);

        // left/right indexes
        i = 0;
        j = n - 1;

        // test all chars in the word
        for (;  i < j;  ++i, --j) {
            // current match?
            c = (s[i] == s[j]);

            // stop if no -- _not_ a palindrome
            if (! c)
                break;
        }

        if (! c) {
            printf("Not Palindrome -- '%s'\n",s);
            continue;
        }

        // length too long
        if (n > 7) {
            printf("%c%d%c\n", s[0], n - 2, s[n - 1]);
            continue;
        }

        // regular palindrome
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```